# How to do arithmetics with text field in where clause?

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-server

I have an 8-digit TEXT field (called Code) and want to do a select "where Code mod 3 is 0".
How do I write this where clause in ms-sql, in particular? I believe the query should be the same in other versions of SQL. Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Firstly - DONT DO THIS! Putting scalar calculations in where clauses makes them non-SARGable which effectively means you can't use indexes and have to do table scans.

Secondly - DONT DO THIS! If any of your codes can't cast to an INT then this will fail.

Thirdly - If you still want to do this despite the two warnings, this is how:

```
-- If field is varchar
WHERE CAST(Code AS INT) % 3 = 0

-- If field is TEXT
WHERE CAST(CAST(Code AS VARCHAR(10)) AS INT) % 3 = 0
```

Comment: +1 for the right idea; but CAST doesn't work between `TEXT` and `INT` (Assuming OP literally meant the legacy `TEXT` type in MSSQL). You would have to do this: `CAST(CAST(Code as VARCHAR(25)) AS INT)`.

Comment: Thanks for this, I assumed he meant varchar but I added in both possibilities now.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if it's the same in MSSQL, but in MySQL:

```
SELECT * FROM tbl WHERE Code % 3 = 0;
```

Comment: I think OP might have edited the question to say that it was a TEXT field...I don't recall that being there originally. No idea if my solution works or not with a TEXT column.